# Adding multiple graphics to a single JPanel

Tags: java, swing, graphics, awt

I am attempting to add 3 graphics, two of which have to move(presumably through each other, moving on a single axis) and only the lattermost one added to the panel shows.

In other words, I have many panels added to my JFrame, and in the biggest panel I have put in graphics objects using specific coordinates. It may be more helpful to show the code.

```
//the gameArea is the referred-to JPanel, above this code    
TankOne tank1 = new TankOne(Color.GREEN);
TankTwo tank2 = new TankTwo(Color.MAGENTA);
FieldBar fieldb = new FieldBar(Color.getHSBColor((float) Math.random(),(float) Math.random(),(float) Math.random()));
JPanel tank1panel = new JPanel();
JPanel tank2panel = new JPanel();
tank1panel.add(tank1);
tank2panel.add(tank2);
gameArea.add(tank1panel);
gameArea.add(tank2panel);
gameArea.add(fieldb);
//repaint code here
```

As you can see, it is a tank game. 
The one that shows up on the GUI is the last gameArea.add. [Here it would be fieldb, a bar that shows the game floor].

The attempt made here is me trying to put two new panels into the gameArea Jpanel and then placing the two tank objects inside those. Still no dice.

Is there a workaround for this that would allow me to move the tanks by pixels? 
I have seen some answers include switching to gridlayout, but I don't think that will help seeing as the extra Panels did nothing.

Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm guessing that each tank JPanel shows an image of a single tank (? not 100% sure). Some suggestions, but please do tell me if my assumptions are way off base:

- Keep the logic and view well separated a la M-V-C.
- Do all graphics in a single JPanel, perhaps called a DrawingPanel, in its `paintComponent(...)` method.
- The Background image will be a BufferedImage that is draw in the DrawingPanel's `paintComponent(...)` method.
- The a tank itself would not be represented by a JPanel but would be its own small BufferedImage sprite, again draw in the paintComponent method, but drawn **after** the background image.
- Each tank would need at least 4 sprites, one for each direction.
- You may need more sprites if your tanks will move along a diagonal.
- And a separate sprite/image for the turret.
- You would move a sprite's drawn position in response to changes of it's model representation's position.
- Same thing for turret rotation.